# Docker build in Jenkins

Tags: jenkins, docker

When running job with Docker build and publish I get exception Please find the exception below

> git config core.sparsecheckout # timeout=10
>   git checkout -f 82bb778d55f0a9a5020c23aa5dfa62db79de2e28
>   git rev-list 82bb778d55f0a9a5020c23aa5dfa62db79de2e28 # timeout=10 [example]
>
> $ docker build -t adithi11/demo-example:v9 --pull=true /Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/example

```
ERROR: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/example"): error=2, No such file or directory
java.io.IOException: Cannot run program "docker" (in directory "/Users/Shared/Jenkins/Home/workspace/example"): error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1048)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:245)
    at hudson.Proc$LocalProc.<init>(Proc.java:214)
    at hudson.Launcher$LocalLauncher.launch(Launcher.java:846)
    at hudson.Launcher$ProcStarter.start(Launcher.java:384)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:487)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.executeCmd(DockerBuilder.java:431)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.buildAndTag(DockerBuilder.java:373)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.exec(DockerBuilder.java:311)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder$Perform.access$100(DockerBuilder.java:291)
    at com.cloudbees.dockerpublish.DockerBuilder.perform(DockerBuilder.java:262)
    at hudson.tasks.BuildStepMonitor$1.perform(BuildStepMonitor.java:20)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.perform(AbstractBuild.java:779)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.build(Build.java:205)
    at hudson.model.Build$BuildExecution.doRun(Build.java:162)
    at hudson.model.AbstractBuild$AbstractBuildExecution.run(AbstractBuild.java:534)
    at hudson.model.Run.execute(Run.java:1728)
    at hudson.model.FreeStyleBuild.run(FreeStyleBuild.java:43)
    at hudson.model.ResourceController.execute(ResourceController.java:98)
    at hudson.model.Executor.run(Executor.java:404)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: error=2, No such file or directory
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.forkAndExec(Native Method)
    at java.lang.UNIXProcess.<init>(UNIXProcess.java:248)
    at java.lang.ProcessImpl.start(ProcessImpl.java:134)
    at java.lang.ProcessBuilder.start(ProcessBuilder.java:1029)
    ... 19 more
Build step 'Docker Build and Publish' marked build as failure
Finished: FAILURE
```

But when i sudo to jenkins I get this

sudo su jenkins
    docker images
    Got permission denied while trying to connect to the Docker daemon socket at unix:///var/run/docker.sock: Get http://%2Fvar%2Frun%2Fdocker.sock/v1.25/images/json: dial unix /var/run/docker.sock: connect: permission denied

Would appreciate your assistance

Answer (score 2):

```
# Add the docker group if it doesn't already exist.
$ sudo groupadd docker

# Add jenkins user to docker group. 
$ sudo gpasswd -a jenkins docker

# Restart the Docker daemon.
$ sudo service docker restart
```

Logout and login again for the changes to apply